# How to run a Vercel serverless function in a static HTML file?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I have the following project directory:

```
a_vercel_test
|
+--- index.html
|
+--- pages
     |
     +--- api
          |
          +--- index.js
```

I ran `vercel dev` inside the folder to get it running. When I go to `localhost:3000`, I can find the contents of the `index.html` file properly rendered. For the record, the `index.html` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>A Vercel Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>A Vercel Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The `index.js` file looks like this:

```
// pages/api/index.js'

export default function handler(req, res) {
  console.log('Running Function');
}
```

Now what I want to do is run this as a serverless function when the HTML file is loaded. The reason I want to do this is that I want to query some data in this function (using env db secrets), and pass it to my file for rendering. Is this actually possible to do using such bare bones setup on Vercel? And if so, how do I do this? Most examples in the docs are related to `next.js`, and are also a bit confusing to be honest. I would love to be able to keep everything really light and static.